# Retrieve different customer status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a query to retrieve the result from the table.

When the name all my statuses are completed to show me completed. When the status has completed but there is another status such as in progress or  created then show only the other status

| CustomName | STATUS | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ivan Ivanov | completed | 1 |
| Stoqn Stoqnov | completed | 1 |
| Dimityr Ivanov | completed | 1 |
| Ivan Ivanov | completed | 2 |
| Dimityr Ivanov | completed | 2 |
| Ivan Ivanov | inprocess | 2 |
| Stoqn Stoqnov | completed | 2 |
| Dimityr Ivanov | completed | 3 |
| Dimityr Ivanov | created | 4 |
| Stoqn Stoqnov | completed | 3 |
| Ivan Ivanov | completed | 4 |
| Stoqn Stoqnov | completed | 4 |

Expected result

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Ivan Ivanov | inprocess |
| Dimityr Ivanov | created |
| Stoqn Stoqnov | completed |

Query:

```
SELECT distinct  CustomName,
(CASE WHEN  [STATUS] ='COMPLETED'    THEN 'completed' 
WHEN  [STATUS] ='inprocess' THEN 'inprocess' 
WHEN  [STATUS] ='created' THEN 'created'  END  ) AS [STATUS]
from [dbo].[Customers]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following where you count how many of each status there are per customer and then choose in a priority order which to display.

```
declare @Test table (CustomName varchar(32), [STATUS] varchar(32), [Order] int)

insert into @Test (CustomName, [STATUS], [Order])
values
('Ivan Ivanov',     'completed',   1),
('Stoqn Stoqnov',   'completed',   1),
('Dimityr Ivanov',  'completed',   1),
('Ivan Ivanov',     'completed',   2),
('Dimityr Ivanov',  'completed',   2),
('Ivan Ivanov',     'inprocess',   2),
('Stoqn Stoqnov',   'completed',   2),
('Dimityr Ivanov',  'completed',   3),
('Dimityr Ivanov',  'created',     4),
('Stoqn Stoqnov',   'completed',   3),
('Ivan Ivanov',     'completed',   4),
('Stoqn Stoqnov',   'completed',   4);

with cte as (
    select CustomName
      , sum(case when [status] = 'completed' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by CustomName) Completed
      , sum(case when [status] = 'created' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by CustomName) Created
      , sum(case when [status] = 'inprocess' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by CustomName) InProcess
    from @Test
)
select CustomName
    -- This logic could be more complex if desired
    , case when InProcess > 0 then 'In Process' when Created > 0 then 'Created' else 'Completed' end
from cte
group by CustomName, Completed, Created, InProcess;
```

Returns:

| CustomName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Dimityr Ivanov | Created |
| Ivan Ivanov | In Process |
| Stoqn Stoqnov | Completed |

Note: Providing the DDL+DML as I have shown, makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: I don't get why this needs window functions: you are grouping anyway, so just use a standard conditional aggregates

Comment: @Charlieface - yip sometimes I overcomplicate things :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this needs window functions or cross joins, **just a simple `GROUP BY` with conditional counts**

```sql
SELECT
  CustomName,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 'created'   THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Created'
       WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 'inprocess' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'In Process'
       ELSE 'Completed' END
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.CustomName;
```

Comment: this one is not working properly
but thank you very much for everyone's quick response

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

The idea is to use `cte` to find all Customer Name who contain different type of status

and then use `UNION ALL` to find all Customer Name who **ONLY** contains "Completed" status

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT CustomName, [STATUS]
    FROM [dbo].[Customers]
    WHERE [STATUS] <> 'Completed'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT CustomName, [STATUS]
FROM [dbo].[Customers]
WHERE CustomName NOT IN (SELECT CustomName FROM cte)
```